# How can I tether an Olympus E-M5 II to Lightroom?

Tags: olympus, tethering, studio

I was wondering what would be needed to tether an Olympus E-M5 II to Lightroom.

I want to have the images pop up on my MacBook during a photoshoot to see a larger image and have a possibility to edit on the spot.

Is this possible? And if so what would be needed to do this?—*I.e.,* what hardware,software and set up process would be needed?

Answer (score 1):

With Olympus Capture software and a usb cable you can do tethered shooting with an E-M5 II and import the photos directly into Lightroom.

You can also operate the E-M5 II with an iPad or iPhone using the camera's built-in wifi and the ol.share app. The photos are stored on the tablet's camera roll and can be edited with Lightroom for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible - I do with an EM-5 Mk I. You should be able to use an Eyefi card.  I use it for wireless tethered shooting with the images going directly into Lightroom. It can be setup to automatically upload photos to a Mac, and you can set an auto-import folder for Lightroom and have the Eyefi software put the incoming images into that folder.  I can send both RAW and JPEG images. Transmission should happen automatically when the camera and Mac connect with each other on the wifi network. Sometimes my camera will get confused and stop sending, and I have to turn the camera off and back on to get things going again.  There should be detailed setup instructions on the Eyefi web site.